# Specify range from -x to x

Tags: jupyter-notebook, range, counting

I want my code to count up to a number n and then down to where it started, for example of n=4:

1
2
3
4
3
2
1

I've used range() to get from 1-4, and then reversed(range()) to get to 4-1, but they're two seperate blocks (and I'd get two 4's) and I'm sure there is a better and cleaner way. I've tried to specify the range from -n to n, but I honestly have no idea if I should use length, range or slices or whatever. I'm very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the abs function as well to figure this out. 
Try something like the following

```
n = 4;
for i in map(lambda x: n - abs(x),range(0-n+1, n)):
    print(i)
```

Output should be like the following,

```
1
2
3
4
3
2
1
```

You could also wrap this and return an enumerator like the following,

```
def riseAndFall(n):
    for i in map(lambda x: n - abs(x),range(0-n+1, n)):
        yield i

for i in riseAndFall(4):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I want n to be specified by the user input, but when I write

Is it reasonable to be able to draw this conclusion after one week of programming classes? What does lambda do in this equation and is abs referrng to absolute value?

Comment: abs: absolute value.
lambda: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp